# React server side rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I’m trying to figure out how to render landing pages of my react js and node js site to be optimized for seo. Right now I use react for the front end and a proxy to access node api at a different port. Any suggestions on how I can render landing pages server side would be great

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) for SSR.

> Next.js is a JavaScript framework created by [Zeit](https://zeit.co/). It lets you build
>   server-side rendering and static web applications using React.

Here are some cool features Next.js brings to the table taken from [Learn Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started):

- Server-rendered by default
- Automatic code splitting for faster page loads
- Simple client-side routing (page based)
- Webpack-based dev environmet which supports Hot Module Replacement (HMR)
- Able to implement with Express or any other Node.js HTTP server
- Customizable with your own Babel and Webpack configurations